# How can I make this 2 functions work in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning Python. Why do I get the error `Exception in Tkinter callback`? 
I'm trying to Browse the file from the button "Browse" and zip the file in "Compress" button. I don't know what is wrong with my code? Please help!

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import tkFileDialog
    import gzip

    class SecureBox(Frame):

        def browse(self):
            return tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

        def compressFile(self):   
            f_in = open(self.browse, 'rb')
            f_out = gzip.open('compressFile.gz', 'wb')
            f_out.writelines(f_in)
            f_out.close()
            f_in.close()

        def createWidgets(self):
            # Pick a file from user
            self.compress = Button(self)
            self.compress["text"] = "1. Browse"
            self.compress["command"] = self.browse
            self.compress["fg"] = "blue"
            self.compress.pack({"side": "top"})            

            # Pick a file from user and compress the file
            self.compress = Button(self)
            self.compress["text"] = "2. Compress"
            self.compress["command"] = self.compressFile
            self.compress["fg"] = "blue"
            self.compress.pack({"side": "top"})
# Adding this function to get the widget show up
        def __init__(self, master):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.pack()
            self.createWidgets() 
    root = Tk()
    root.title ("Secure Box")
    root.geometry("500x350")

    sb = SecureBox(root)
    # start the program
    sb.mainloop()

    root.destroy()
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback error message?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by linking functions in this case. You mean to cause functions to execute when some buttons are clicked? Edit: the code isn't running right on my box. No buttons appear.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback is the error I got. I mean "link" is how can I get the result from the button "Browse" and put in the button "Compress"?

Comment: Please edit the question text to specify this, thank you :) Space and formatting here is far more limited than it would be above.

Comment: I added the missing code to get the program works. Please try to run it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it runs now. Sorry, I haven't done much Tk work myself. But this should help people who know better.

Answer (score 2):

Save the filename as a class attribute, and use that to open the file:

```
def browse(self):
    self.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

def compressFile(self):   
    f_in = open(self.filename, 'rb')
    ...
```

---

**Explanation:**

Basically, when you're doing `open(self.browse, 'rb')` you're passing a function reference to `open` instead of a filename. This won't work, since `open` cannot open a function, it can open files. You could use `open(self.browse(), 'rb')` since `self.browse()` returns a filename, but that would render your `Browse` button useless, since the file dialog would then be opened when you click the `Compress` button.

When saving the filename as a class attribute and using that to open the file as I propose above, you also don't need the `return` in the `browse` function. In Tkinter, a button callback is called without any arguments and no return arguments are saved, so returning anything doesn't do anything. If you choose to do remove the browse button altogether and use the `open(self.browse(), 'rb')` method, you do need to return the filename (but it doesn't need to be a class attribute).